# downloaded file from FTP as stream, cannot open as filestream?

Tags: c#, ftp

I have used a library called fluentFTP to get a list of files to download (.csv) and upload.

I first connect, download the file to a Stream object (forcefully so) and then save as a dataset.

```
        ftpClient.Connect();
        var stream = ftpClient.OpenRead(filePath);
        var config = new ExcelDataSetConfiguration { ConfigureDataTable = _ => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration { UseHeaderRow = true } };
        IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateCsvReader(stream);
```

when excelReader trys to open the Stream object I get the below error. Im assuming because CreateCsvReader takes a FileStream object not a Stream.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.'
```

I dont see a method that returns a FileStream, am I screwed or is there a way to convert this Stream object to a FileStream.  the file downloaded is a .CSV file

Are there any good other FTP clients I can try? Most of my connections are SFTP which work fine because SSH.NET provides a method that returns a filestream. Unfortunately sftp does not work with ftp as its completely different protocol

Comment: *Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object* well, what's the state of the object? Also, calling `ToString()` on exceptions is preferable than copying Message as there might be inner exceptions.

Comment: I don't know how the object could have a state because I just created it.

Comment: You should look at it while debugging.

Answer (score -1):

Look at the FluentFTP documentation and follow their example:

https://github.com/robinrodricks/FluentFTP/blob/master/FluentFTP.Examples/BeginOpenRead.cs

```
namespace Examples {
    public static class BeginOpenReadExample {
        static ManualResetEvent m_reset = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        public static void BeginOpenRead() {
            // The using statement here is OK _only_ because m_reset.WaitOne()
            // causes the code to block until the async process finishes, otherwise
            // the connection object would be disposed early. In practice, you
            // typically would not wrap the following code with a using statement.
            using (FtpClient conn = new FtpClient()) {
                m_reset.Reset();

                conn.Host = "localhost";
                conn.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("ftptest", "ftptest");
                conn.BeginOpenRead("/path/to/file",
                    new AsyncCallback(BeginOpenReadCallback), conn);

                m_reset.WaitOne();
                conn.Disconnect();
            }
        }

        static void BeginOpenReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar) {
            FtpClient conn = ar.AsyncState as FtpClient;

            try {
                if (conn == null)
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("The FtpControlConnection object is null!");

                using (Stream istream = conn.EndOpenRead(ar)) {
                    byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
                    ...
```

Comment: I don't see how this helps me at all? I've already connected to the ftp server, i've gotten the file path, and i've written it to a Stream object called stream.  I still cannot pass a Stream object to ExcelReaderFactory.CreateCsvReader() because it only takes a filestream

Comment: Sorry - I had the impression you weren't able to create a stream at all.  Of course, one workaround might be to read the FtpClient stream into a temporary disk file, then re-open the temp file as a FileStream (just to satisfy `ExcelReaderFactory.CreateCsvReader()`).  But if [ExcelDataReader](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader) actually *REQUIRES* a FileStream (instead of just a generic "Stream") ... maybe you should find a different Excel library?  Why not use Microsoft's OOTB Excel libraries?